# How to add a user in an SQL Server database with the same rights as in another one on the same server?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a server in SQL Server Management Studio, in this one when I open the "Security" folder, then "Connections" I have different user accounts already created.

I have two databases: `RCE`, and `RCE_Finance_BI`.
In the first one in the "Security" folder, then "Users" I have these accounts :

[image]

Including JeromeRCE who has write and read rights on this database.

Now in the RCE_Finance_BI database I have these users:

[image]

I would like to add to this database the `JeromeRCE` account and give him the same rights as in the RCE database, i.e. read and write rights.

How can I do it please?

Comment: Use the `CREATE USER` and then `GRANT`/`DENY` that `USER` the needed permissions or add to them the `ROLE`(s) that it needs to be added to. [CREATE USER (Transact-SQL)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-user-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15), [GRANT Object Permissions (Transact-SQL)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/grant-object-permissions-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15), [ALTER ROLE (Transact-SQL)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/alter-role-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15).

Comment: So we have to do it with a script, can't we do it on SQL Server Management Studio via an interface? @Larnu

Comment: Yes, you can right click the security folder and go to New->User . Sounds like, therefoer, you should be talking to your DBA to do this though if you're not familiar with the GUI.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can do it.

1. use the below script

```
USE [RCE_Finance_BI]
GO

CREATE USER [JeromeRCE] FOR LOGIN [JeromeRCE] WITH DEFAULT_SCHEMA=[dbo]
GO
```

Or you can create the script by below steps

1. Right click the user
2. Select 'Script User as'
3. Select 'Create To'
4. Select 'New Query Editor Window'
5. Change the database to you target database in the script.

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I will do that!